# How do not to round the number in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a query like this:

```
Select Customer,JobType,sum(SThours),
sum(OThours),SortMonth,
str((sum(OThours)/sum(SThours)),5,2)AS Ratios 
from #data
group by Customer,JobType,SortMonth


Sum (SThours): 688
sum(OThours): 618
```

The ratio should be 618/688=0.90 but my result is 1.00

I am new to SQL, and I need help. Thanks.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting the number to decimal

```
SELECT
  Customer,
  JobType,
  sum(SThours),
  sum(OThours),
  SortMonth,
  str((CAST(sum(OThours) AS DECIMAL)/sum(SThours) ),5,2) AS Ratios
FROM
   #data
GROUP BY
  Customer,  JobType,  SortMonth
```

Try this sample [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/5316)

it is simple example showing getting decimal values

Answer (score 3):

Try casting one or other side of the division to a float - to force floating point rather than integer division.

```
SELECT
  Customer,
  JobType,
  sum(SThours),
  sum(OThours),
  SortMonth,
  str((CAST(sum(OThours) AS FLOAT)/sum(SThours)),5,2) AS Ratios
FROM
  #data
GROUP BY
  Customer,
  JobType,
  SortMonth
```

Comment: i try the code, But i still get the same result. i use the sql query in crystla report.

Comment: I get it, When i declare the Ratios i set numeric now i change to numeric (10,2). thanks for you help. that save me a day

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're performing an integer division, which will always result in an integer value in return.
You should cast the sums to a floating point numeric value (decimal should work) before dividing them.